# Use Wildcard / Regex in filter settings of SSMS object explorer to find an object

Tags: sql, regex, sql-server-2008, wildcard, ssms

Is there a way to fine tune the SQL Server Management Studio Filter Settings results (in the Object Explorer) by using wildcards to find objects like `XYZ_unknown_abc` using a `Contains` operator?

I tried `(XYZ*abc)` or `(XYZ abc)` with no luck.

Comment: Is `LIKE` operator not working?

Comment: Trying to find stored, tables etc like here http://www.nullskull.com/fileupload/-1496670726_Filter.jpg and here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181166%28SQL.90%29.aspx

Comment: No, unfortunately, the filter is a very simple search - explicit contains only as far as I can tell. You can narrow down on the leading or trailing string, and inspect manually from there. If this is too much (you must have a whole lot of redundant objects), then you can use much more powerful pattern matching using LIKE / PATINDEX in a query window against sys.objects, sys.tables, sys.views, etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Coming a bit late, but %XYZ%abc% in the search box shows db object with names containing XYZ and abc, in that order.

Comment: It searches all DB objects and shows all objects types but we still have the sorting tab. thank you it will sure help.

Answer (score 1):

Wildcards are still not allowed in the filter setting within Object Explorer in SSMS. BTW .. you can check this new set of Operators: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2005/ms181166(v=sql.90)

Answer (score 0):

For anyone still interested, I typically use this query to different schemas, tables, and/or columns:

```
    SELECT DISTINCT TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME, COUNT(*) 
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA LIKE '%%' 
      AND TABLE_NAME LIKE '%XYZ%abc%' 
      AND (COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%%' AND COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%%')
    GROUP BY TABLE_SCHEMA, COLUMN_NAME, TABLE_NAME
    ORDER BY 1,2,3
```